# Tips horizontal scroll with textbox

Tags: java, android

I would like to make horizontal swipe scroll with images and text views on it, 3-4 views.

Like tips screen on applications.

But, don't know which component to use, I need something like tabs(3-4 different layouts) but I dont want to show tab menu up. Just full screen, few buttons down, and in middle textbox with tip(which i want to animate later), everything is same in every layout just different image and text.

No code here in question because i stuck on beginning and need few tips what to use or some linked tutorial.

Comment: Use a ViewFlipper (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

Comment: Try using RecyclerView with Horizontal LinearLayoutManager

Comment: @drWisdom, can i use different layout for ViewFlipper? 3 xml layouts?

Comment: @Sasaman yes you can, as my comment is going to be detailed I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this.

> ```
> <ViewFlipper
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:id="@+id/pro_flip"
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent">
>             //put your child elements for first page on this layout
>           </LinearLayout>
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent">
>               //put your child elements for second page on this layout
>           </LinearLayout>>         
> </ViewFlipper>
> ```
>
> Content on the first layout will be visible to the user at first, when he swipes the next layout will be loaded. 
>   ViewFlipper should be sufficient for simple content like you mentioned. If you want something more look into ViewPager.